# How to get Object Index by Value?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

**ANSWERED by Fissio**

I am trying to make a simple search feature in Angular.  When the user types in something in the input field, I want to search through all the 'titles' in my JSON, and if a word matches with the input, then I want to bring back all the objects related to the match.

**FACTORY**

I first created a Factory to retrieve data from JSON using a Promise.

```
.factory('podcastData', function($http) {

var podcastData = {

    async: function() {
        var promise = $http.get('http://radio-sante-animale.fr/podcast-data.php').then(function(response) {
            return response.data.categories;
        })
        return promise;
    }

};

return podcastData;

})
```

Then in my controller, I tried to do a search program in my Controller. 
What I attempted so far, I managed to do a for loop, I got the length of the array, I then got all the 'Podcasts' in the array, and I then managed to get all the values matched with the input.

**CONTROLLER**

*Updated*

```
$scope.findValue = function(enteredValue) {
    console.log(enteredValue);
    var filtered = [];
    podcastData.async().then(function(data) {
        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            angular.forEach(data[i].podcasts, function(podcasts, key) {

                var foundPodcasts = _.filter(podcasts, function(podcast) {                       
                    return podcasts.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(enteredValue) >= 0
                });

                if (typeof foundPodcasts !== 'undefined') {
                    filtered.concat(foundPodcasts);
                    console.log(foundPodcasts);
                };                 
            });
        }
    });

}
```

I updated my controller, now I do get in return all the objects that matches the search input, however when I console.log **foundPodcasts**, this is my response.  This is good!  However, there is empty arrays in between, and I am not able to do a NG-REPEAT, since there is no VALUE that I can grab.

[image]

Comment: Can you show us the json of the "data". What properties does it contains?

Comment: Hi Anon, sure!  http://radio-sante-animale.fr/podcast-data.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Took the liberty of changing `filtered` into array; I understood you wanted to find ALL the matching movies, whereas in your code you were just recreating the `filtered` object on each match.

```
$scope.findValue = function(enteredValue) {
    var filtered = [];
    podcastData.async().then(function(data) {
        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var foundPodcasts = _.filter(data[i].podcasts, function(podcast) {
                return podcast.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(enteredValue) >= 0
            });
            if (typeof foundPodcasts !== 'undefined') {
                filtered = filtered.concat(foundPodcasts);
            };
        }
    console.log(filtered);
    return filtered;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, however in your return 'podcast.title.toLowerCase()...',   podcast.title is not found, trying to figure out how I can grab the title value

Comment: @anon, that's my bad - noticed another mistake as well. Try the one I edited in now. I ran it myself and it worked fine.